# Java Script inline function for Anchor tag

Tags: javascript, inline

I'm trying to open a URL in new window and want to share the current page address using inline function as below:

```js
a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick='(function()
{
    var link = string.concat("example.com/UserStatus.phpid=99244613&utm_source=",window.location.href);
    console.log(link);
});return false;'>click here</a>
```

But nothing is happening, please help.

Comment: I'm using below code:<a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="(function()
{
    var link = string.concat('example.com/UserStatus.php?id=99244613&utm_source=',window.location.href);
    console.log(link);
});
return false;">click here</a>

Comment: Could you post a more complete example? Also this could would be much more readable if you extracted the `onClick` into a separate, named function somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that you were using `string.concat` but the right way to use is `"".concat`:

```
function fun(){
  var link = "".concat("example.com/UserStatus.phpid=99244613&utm_source=", window.location.href); 
  console.log(link); 
}

fun();
```

Output will be:

`example.com/UserStatus.phpid=99244613&utm_source=https://playcode.io/`

HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick='fun();'>click here
</a>
```

So in your code just use `"".concat` instead of `string.concat`.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="(function(){
   var link = ''.concat(`example.com/UserStatus.phpid=99244613&utm_source=`,window.location.href); console.log(link);
   return false;
   })();return false;">click here
</a>
```

[Working Codepen Link](https://codepen.io/prasannabrabourame/pen/KKdEBrP)